# CSS :not() is not working as I would expect

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've got the following HTML and CSS code which can also be found and played with here //jsfiddle.net/0k1qah6x/7/

My intent is for the number "1" which has the class "active" not to be red.

```css
.pdf-pagination a:not(.active) {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pdf-pagination">
  <ul>
    <li class="disabled">
      <a id="pdfPaginationLink0" href="#" data-page="0">←</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a id="pdfPaginationLink1" href="#" data-page="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="pdfPaginationLink2" href="#" data-page="2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="pdfPaginationLink3" href="#" data-page="2">→</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `a` element has no class active you must need to target the `li` instead

Comment: `.active` is on the `li` so you want `.pdf-pagination li:not(.active) a`.

Answer (score 5):

Your anchors don't  have the `.active` class, their parent `li` do.

You'll have to change your selector and move the `:not()` <del>de</del>selector to the parent, as follows:

```css
.pdf-pagination li:not(.active) a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pdf-pagination">
  <ul>
    <li class="disabled">
      <a id="pdfPaginationLink0" href="#" data-page="0">←</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a id="pdfPaginationLink1" href="#" data-page="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="pdfPaginationLink2" href="#" data-page="2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="pdfPaginationLink3" href="#" data-page="2">→</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```